# Why are geodesic congruences irrotational?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics, vortex

In Sean Carroll's GR book "Spacetime and Geometry", in Appendix F on geodesic congruences, he defines a (timelike) geodesic congruence as the integral curves vector field so that:

$$U_\mu U_\mu = -1$$

$$U^\nu \nabla_\nu U^\mu  = 0$$

From such a vector field, he defines the rotation of the field as:

$$\omega_{\mu \nu}= \frac{1}{2}(\nabla_\mu U_\nu - \nabla_\mu U_\nu)$$

He shows that $U^\mu \omega_{\mu\nu} = 0$. It is not hard to show that $U_{[ \rho} \nabla_\mu U_{\nu ]}  = 0$, which apparently implies that $U$ is orthogonal to a family of hypersurfaces by the Frobenius Theorem.

My thoughts are that hypersurface orthogonality implies that in some local coordinates, $U^\mu = (1,0,0,0)$. If that were true, we could say
$$\nabla_\mu U_\nu - \nabla_\mu U_\nu = (\partial_\mu U_\nu - {{{\Gamma_\mu}^\rho}_\nu}U_\rho) - (\partial_\nu U_\mu - {{{\Gamma_\nu}^\rho}_\mu}U_\rho) = 0,$$ by cancellation of the Christoffel terms and that the partial derivatives are zero.

Is setting  $U^\mu = (1,0,0,0)$ justified? If not, how do we finish the proof?

Comment: Hypersurface orthogonality would imply that the vector field is proportional to derivative of a scalar. You can use that to derive the equation that is a special case of the Frobenius theorem. You can find the derivation in "Gravitation: Foundations and frontiers" by Thanu Padmanabhan

Comment: Geodesic congruences are certainly not always irrotational, so there is nothing to prove here. Maybe you can take another look at what exactly does Carroll say in the book (I dont have it), or rewrite the question so that it is clearer what you are actually asking about.